# Mednafen fullscreen spans multiple monitors

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I am having a problem with Mednafen in fullscreen mode. Everything works great windowed, but when I go into fullscreen mode it spans across both my monitors, making the games impossible to play. Does anyone know of a way I can get it to go fullscreen on just one monitor?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and Mednafen 0.9.38.7. This is the video section the initialization screen -

```
 Initializing video...
  Video Driver: OpenGL
  Video Mode: 768 x 672 x 32 bpp
  Pixel shader: none
  Fullscreen: No
  Special Scaler: None
  Scanlines: Off
  Destination Rectangle: X=0, Y=0, W=768, H=672
  OpenGL Implementation: Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop  3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
```

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to get it to work is to edit the mednafen-09x.cfg file like so:

;Full-screen horizontal resolution.
nes.xres 1920

;Full-screen vertical resolution.
nes.yres 1080

By default, these values are set to 0. Two monitors causes mednafen to split the video output across both of them dead center - making it unplayable.

You'll need to do this for each system you want to emulate in the cfg file. Just change the default value of 0 to your monitor's resolution and it'll work. The only downside is that it kills signal to my #2 monitor while the game is running.